# If JQuery Date Picker equals Sunday then show a different option set

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am wondering if someone can help me!!

I am building a basic form that sends a message with a date/time.
I have a Jquery Date Picker and I want this to determine which option set is displayed in the form.
I want the option set of times to be different for Monday - Saturday than it is on the Sunday, so if the dayOfWeek = 0 then it should display a second option set.

I know it will probably have something to do with the "get day of week" function.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate: 0, dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"});

  // getter
  var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );

  // setter
  $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy" );
});
</script>
```

and in the HTML a table with this in it currently:

```
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <td><input type="text" name="herdate" size="50" class="datepicker"/></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Time From:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="herfroms" >
      <option>08.00</option>
      <option>09.00</option>
      <option>10.00</option>
      <option>11.00</option>
      <option>12.00</option>
      <option>13.00</option>
      <option>14.00</option>
      <option>15.00</option>
      <option>16.00</option>
      <option>17.00</option>
      <option>18.00</option>
      <option>19.00</option>
      <option>20.00</option>
      <option>21.00</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <th>Time To:</th>
  <td>
    <select name="hertos">
      <option>09.00</option>
      <option>10.00</option>
      <option>11.00</option>
      <option>12.00</option>
      <option>13.00</option>
      <option>14.00</option>
      <option>15.00</option>
      <option>16.00</option>
      <option>17.00</option>
      <option>18.00</option>
      <option>19.00</option>
      <option>20.00</option>
      <option>21.00</option>
      <option>22.00</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But I want the option set to be different depending on if the day of the week is Sunday.......

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show your code?

Comment: What datepicker too? The jQuery UI one doesn't have the method you mention.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **jquery**:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onClose : showday
});
function showday() {
    day_no = new Date($(this).val()).getDay();
    if(day_no == 0)//for sundays
        alert("It's sunday!");
        //perform some action for Sunday
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/104/)**.

**EDIT:**

[**New DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/105/).

Comment: by actual one you mean, the one mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yea thats what I meant the one I posted in the question is no longer working.

Comment: thats because you have changed the default date format, you have rechange it to the format when passing to new Date().

Comment: Even with the function to change the date format the date picker is still not displaying.

Comment: I edited my answer, hope it helps ! Your acceptance and upvote are welcome :)